# How to prevent babel-jest from using babel config file in project?

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AcHK.png)

I wrote a package with babel-jest to transform specified js files. I installed this package in my working project and tried to run unit test under the project. There's a `.babelrc` file in my project, so babel-jest would use the babel configuration file automatically, which is not what i want.

> Note: babel-jest is automatically installed when installing Jest and will automatically transform files if a babel configuration exists in your project. To avoid this behavior, you can explicitly reset the transform configuration option:

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "transform": {}
  }
}
```

I tried to reset jest transform in `package.json` file of the project, according to the description in jest docs. But it seemed not working, babel-jest still used the babel configuration file of the project.

Is there any way to avoid using `.babelrc` in project while running jest?

Comment: By the way I'm using jest cli programmatically in the package.